# iOS size of auto layout view

Tags: objective-c, uiview, autolayout

Lets say if I have a parent UIView in which the sub views have dynamic height.
How can I get the size of the parent view (which has the same height as the sum of all sub views' height).

***p.s. All the views are created by AUTO LAYOUT***

or actually I have to add up the heights myself? I wonder if there is a simpler way to find the parent view's height

Answer (score 1):

If `view` is your `UIView`, you can get the height of the parent view (also called [superview](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIView/superview)) with

```
view.superview.frame.size.height
```

Comment: That depends on where you call it - it should work in viewWillAppear because then the views are laid out already.

Comment: oh... I dont even know frame is workable in auto layout... but what if I am not in a ViewController where I dont have viewDidAppear / viewWillAppear ? eg in UICollectionReusableView

Comment: maybe I should ask in this way: I want to get the height of the view and do something afterwards. When do I know the view is laid out? Where should I add my code?

Comment: The view is laid out during the call to [UIViewController layoutSubviews]. You can override this method (make sure to call [super]) and adjust the views afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

self.parentView.superview.frame.size.height

Comment: It is not valid to say "auto layout views" or "views are created by AUTO LAYOUT".  Actually views use auto layout to layout their subviews, and I think this answer will work.

Comment: @dondonhk You can call this in viewWillAppear(), how Glorfindel said, because at this moment all views know their sizes